# Npgsql documentation missing description of objects it provides

Tags: npgsql

Am I missing something?

On the Npgsql [documentation pages](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/), I can't find the name of the assembly and the objects it provides.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

From some of the sample code, I know that one of the objects is called:

```
NpgsqlConnection
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio add a reference to Npgsql to your project, then type F2 to open the "Object Browser" and you can see all the Npgsql classes and their methods.

I think that the Npgsql developers have tried to follow the .Net API (especially in Npgsql V3), so the Npgsql object model closely matches the .Net `System.Data.Common` object model with the "Db" part of the name changed to "Npgsql", so for instance the Npgsql equivalent of `DbConnection` is `NpgsqlConnection`.

I was a little confused when I started using Npgsql because it seems like it is not fully documented, but later I realized that is because it matches the .Net API so closely, you can refer to the .Net documentation directly.

Because Npgsql is so closely "ADO.Net Compliant", you can actually use the .Net interfaces in your code (the only thing specific to Npgsql in the code below is the `New NpgsqlConnection` call):

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim connection As IDbConnection = New NpgsqlConnection("connection string")
    Using trans As IDbTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction
        Dim command As IDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM something;"
        Using dr As IDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read
                'do something
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

There are some differences, and those are documented at http://www.npgsql.org/doc/.